# can can error shown only for one action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am puzzled with my ability.rb (CanCan) issue from past 2 hours.

This is my ability.rb file

```
if account.school_admin?
    can :manage, GameSchool, {account_id: account.id}
  end
```

and my routes is

```
  resources :game_schools do
    member do
      get  'manage_classes'
    end
    collection do
      get 'all_schools_list'
      get 'search'
      get 'show_joiners_requests'
    end
  end
```

But, Now If I log-in as school_admin, and try to execute this 'show_joiners_requests'. Its showing CanCan error . Can I know whats wrong in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have defines ability to manage game school resource if its account_id matches with account's id. Since 'show_joiners_requests' is a collection resource, it is not tied to any particular game school and has no access to any account id.